# BoxShadow dentro de container en un SliverToBoxAdapter

Tags: flutter

estoy intentando crear un ListView Builder horizontal y al intentarlo me aparece un inconveniente referente al espacio que ocupa mi BoxSadow para hacer un efecto visual en un container. Adjunto código e imagen demostrativa:

```
body: CustomScrollView(
    slivers: [
      // Widget: Title of the section
      const SectionTitle(text: 'Actividades del día'),
      SliverToBoxAdapter(
        child: SizedBox(
          // color: Colors.red,
          height: 130,
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: 3,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => const ActivitiesCard(),
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      const SectionTitle(text: 'Pagos pendientes', topPadding: 0),
    ],
  ),


class ActivitiesCard extends StatelessWidget {
const ActivitiesCard({
  Key? key,
}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
    children: [
    Container(
      width: 250,
      height: 95,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        boxShadow: const <BoxShadow>[
          BoxShadow(
            color: Color(0x4D8D8B8B),
            blurRadius: 40,
            offset: Offset(0, 20),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
    const SizedBox(height: 10),
   ],
  );}}
```

[image: Imagen de prueba en dispositivos móviles]

Estoy tratando de corregir que las sombras no terminen en ese punto exacto donde acaba el SliverToBoxAdapter pero no he podido lograrlo sin afectar el estilo que la aplicación requiere. Sin embargo investigando y probando me di cuenta que al extender el ListView hasta un punto máximo esta limitante desaparece.

[image: Demostración en una pantalla más ancha]

¿Cómo puedo hacer que ese comportamiento se mantenga dentro del Listview cuando no todos los elementos están en pantalla?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya encontré una forma de resolverlo, usando la propiedad clipBehavior de la siguiente manera.

```
      SliverToBoxAdapter(
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 130,
          child: ListView.builder(
            physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            clipBehavior: Clip.none,
            itemCount: 3,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => const ActivitiesCard(),
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Esto puede ayudarles si lo necesitan, pero no estoy muy seguro de si es la forma ideal de hacerlo. Cualquier otra solución es bien recibida.

Comment: está bien, por defecto el ListView corta el contenido, con eso le dices que ya no lo haga, otra forma también es que a tu elemento (card) , le des un padding, entonces muestras la sombra abajo del padding y ya no llega a cortar.